# SMS Send Logging Data Extension

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobileconnect, logging, sms

We need to log few additional custom fields after sending SMS from Marketing Cloud using a Journey that has a Salesforce Event and starts after the creation of an opportunity in SF injecting a contact.
If we have the email address empty, we should send an SMS to the Contact's mobile phone. Our aim is to track the Opportunity ID linked to this SMS send.

Do you think is it possible? Have you ever seen any constraints or limitations regarding this matter?

Answer (score 4):

For send logging to a Data Extension, SFMC added the SMS Send Log Data Extension template last year. There's a [knowledge base article](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000233287&type=1) that covers what it is an how to use it.

One of the challenges would be that MobileConnect has a separate data model where in order to send an SMS, the contact has to be subscribed to a MobileConnect keyword. So, in order to get a Journey Builder Interaction to work correctly, you'd need to add your new Contact to MobileConnect, either through an Automation (Import Mobile Contacts activity) or by MobileConnect's API - most likely using the [QueueMO](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/postQueueMO.htm) or [MessageContact](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/postMessageContactSend.htm) routes that both have variations for creating your contact with your CRM ContactID as the SubscriberKey as they send a message.

Comment: Hi @AndrewMcLeod, I already knew the SMS send log data extension. I need to add new fields to this DE, but the problem is finding a way in order to log opportunity id in the sms send log. I understood from your response that I should add few fields or probably a completely new DE linked to mobile demographic DE in contact builder's attribute groups. Then I should import the opportunity id and subscriber data into mobile connect daily every morning; however I could have more than one opportunity assigned to the same contact (1to many). I am wondering how MC can choose the correct opportunity.

Comment: I understand, I think. Logging isn't so much your problem, but rather the lack of "data binding" with MobileConnect where the data associated with the event isn't available in the context of the SMS send.

Comment: I'd consider approaching differently. Either create a custom Journey Builder activity that uses MobileConnect's QueueMO endpoint to post the data for personalisation in realtime in your Interaction, or use SSJS to run in Automation Studio that does similar while looping through recently added records to the event or a table you use log to with Update Contact activity in your interaction. The custom activity for JB feels neater, but a bit beyond what I can give here.